# Output array values to template

Tags: json, angular, angular-template

I'm currently learning Angular 2 and have confused myself with how to output data returned from a service to my template.

My API Response :

```
{
  "site": {
    "success": true,
    "title": "foo",
    "description": "bar"
  }
}
```

My Service :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import  {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


 @Injectable()
 export class ContentService {
     constructor(private _http:Http) {}

     getContent() {
         return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/foobar-endpoint/')
             .map((res:Response) => res.json())
     }

 }
```

My Component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentService } from "../../services/content/content.service";

const template = require('./home.jade');
const styles = require('./home.sass');

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: template,
    styleUrls: [styles]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public foo = {}

    constructor(private _contentService: ContentService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getContent();
    }

    getContent() {
        this._contentService.getContent()
            .subscribe(
                data => {this.foo = data},
                err => { console.log(err) },
                () => console.log()
            );
    }

}
```

My Template :

```
pre
    p {{ foo.site.title }}
```

If I place `{{ foo | json }}` in my template I can see the returned values in a JSON format, but when I try and output a single value, such as `title` I get undefined errors.

How can I access the values being returned?

Comment: can you please update your question with your template code for which you get undefined error ?

Comment: Hey, thank you, I've updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you are missing here is the `?`. Basically the problem is that when the components instantiates your `foo` property has no `site` param so angular throws the error.

So what you can do is either this:

```
{{foo.site?.title}}
```

Or this:

```
<p *ngIf="foo.site">{{foo.site.title}}</p>
```

This way angular won't try to bind the title before there is a site.

Comment: Thank you so much!